# How to make simple one function read my previous answer and give different output? (c++)

Tags: c++

So, im a very beginner in programming and i was making a simple code snippet to read user input and output persons First, Middle and Lastname.

I made 3 different functions for those inputs and outputs, but i was thinking, is it possible to make 1 function to do all this (in simple code language, im still a very beginner)?

Does it have something to do with Arrays and pointers?

My code snippet would be something like:

```
std::string getUserInput()
{

    std::cout << "Please write your first name: " ;
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

So, i would like it to read my previous answer and give me a different std::cout output i.e "Please write your middle name".

Thank you for your kind answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You'll want to use function arguments:

```
std::string getUserInput(std::string what)
{
    std::cout << "Please write your " << what << ": " ;
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::string first_name = getUserInput("first name");
    std::string middle_name = getUserInput("middle name");
    ...
}
```

Note: As was pointed out in the comments, it would be a good idea to pass `what` as a `const` reference.

In the above example, the whole string is unneccesarily copied when the function is called. You can avoid that by instead writing the function header as

```
std::string getUserInput(const std::string &what)
```

When you write it like that, `getUserInput` will work on the same string object instead of copying it. It is a property of `C++` that you should always have in mind when writing fast code. I left it out here to keep things as simple as possible.

By specifying `const`, you prevent `getUserInput` from modifying the string. In this case, the string cannot be modified because you call the function with constant string literals as arguments (e.g. `"first name"`). These must never be modified in `C` or `C++`, or horrible things will happen (namely, your application will probably crash). Your `C++` compiler will thus prevent you from compiling your code when `what` is a non-const reference.

Comment: Just wondering because I am not super experienced in C++... since `what` is a reference variable shouldn't it be a `const std::string&`?

Comment: @OutlawLemur It *should* be, but not because it is a "reference variable" (which it's not). We pass by reference to `const` because 1) we don't need to modify the variable and 2) we don't need to copy the string which would happen if we pass it by value. So I would suggest the mic_e change the parameter to `std::string const&` as well.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why is it not considered a reference variable? Reference variables are not modified, as `what` isn't

Comment: @OutlawLemur `what` is not declared to be a reference. If we did `std::string& what`, then it would be a reference, but we still have the ability to modify it. That's really one of the purposes of a non-const reference, so we can modify an object through another object. (Also, if we did `std::string&` it wouldn't compile because you can't bind an lvalue-reference to a rvalue). That's also another reason why we use a `const` reference, so it can still bind that way.

Comment: This is actually really easy and simple way to do what i was looking for! I really didnt understand the comments too much, but im still really happy that you guys answered so thoroughly and fast! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @user3476851 Passing `std::string what` to the function makes a copy of it, but this can be inefficient for complex types. So they can be passed as `const std::string& what`. This prevents a copy as the original variable outside the function is used and the const prevents you modifying the variable outside the function by accident.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple thing, do you need a separate function each?

```
std::cout << "Please write your first name: " ;
std::string first;
std::cin >> first;

std::cout << "Please write your middle name: " ;
std::string middle;
std::cin >> middle;

std::cout << "Please write your last name: " ;
std::string last;
std::cin >> last;
```

You could put the name parts into a concatenated string, or a struct, depending how you use it later.

Comment: Ah, i see now! It seems i wanted to be more clever than i actually was! I want to try and immerse myself as much as i can in C++, which i only started a while ago. So, it seems i want my programs to be more complex than they need to be. Shame on me :) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the values using `map<>`

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<int, std::string> values;
std::vector<std::string> names;
values[0] = "first";
...

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "Please write your " << values[i] << " name" << endl;
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    names.push_back(name);
}
```

Comment: What about the code that actually does the extraction?

Comment: Why do you make the value `char[]` and not `std::string`? That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `values[i]`

Comment: I said *extraction*, that's just printing out the strings.

Comment: @Neil Haha no reason really... I guess Ill change it

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh I thought he just wanted to loop through... Check edits

Comment: I think the edit just further complicates things. This is a beginner.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `map`s and `vector`s are very essential to programming in C++

Comment: The `std::map` in this example isn't even needed. You could have easily used an array of strings as well. And while those two constructs are essential to programming, I wouldn't throw all of this to the OP at once before he starts learning it on his own.

Comment: @0x499602D2 An array is not nearly as dynamic as a `map` or `vector`, but yes I could have used an array in hindsight.

Comment: Your answer was really good. I understand how it works, but im not sure if im able to apply it in a different situation, since im still very beginner. Thank you for your answer, i really appreciate it!!

Comment: @user3476851 No problem! There is nothing wrong with calling functions, and often it is better than this approach, it is just for when you have many pairs of values that you wish to modify or reference, and I think it is important that you do understand functions and methods better than specific types, as there is documentation you can always use.

Comment: @OutlawLemur Btw, what does the values.size() function do? I think i could get more out of this, i could see the whole code.. as i said im a very beginner :S :)

Comment: @user3476851 Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/size/)... It is the *"The number of elements in the container."*

Comment: @OutlawLemur That made everything crystal clear! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @OutlawLemur Btw, i tried your method, but i couldnt figure out, how i could print out the persons full name. As i said im a very beginner. I tried dozen of different things, including **std::cout<<std::vector.size;** and **vector.names** but seems, that i just cant figure it out. It says that im missing template arguments before '.' token.

Comment: @user3476851 To print them out, you would use a `for` loop the same way that I receive the values, except that you would be looping through `names` and printing that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the three in one input from user too.

```
cout << "Please write your firstname secondname lastname (with spaces): " << endl;

std::string fName,mName,lName;    
cin >> fName >> mName >> lName;

cout << "First name : " << fName << " Second name: " << mName << "Last name " << lName << endl;
```

Comment: This isnt exactly what i was looking for. But i suppose this can be handy in some other situation. Thank you very much for your answer! :)